# Error when using a dropdown search - mySQL/php

Tags: php, mysql

When trying to incorporate a dropdown option in mySQL search, I keep getting this error:
Warning: in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, boolean given on line 24

Can anyone help? Thank you so much!

Search page:

```
<?php require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/includes/session.php");?>
<?php require($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/includes/db_connection.php");?>
<?php require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/includes/functions.php");?>

<?php include("../includes/header-home.php"); ?>
<div class="container">
  <div class="col=md-12">
    <p><strong>Search:</strong></p>
   <form name="form1" method="post" action="search_results.php">
    <p><input name="search" type="text" size="40" maxlength="50"/></p>
    <p><strong>Type:</strong></p>
     <input type="checkbox" name="type[]" value="1"> Medalist</p>
<select name="medal[]">
<option value="1">Medal 1</option>
<option value="2">Medal 2</option>
<option value="3">Medal 3</option>
<option value="4">Medal 4</option>
<option value="5">Medal 5</option>
<option value="6">Medal 6</option>
<option value="7">Medal 7</option>
<option value="8">Medal 8</option>
</select>

<p><strong>Year:</strong></p>
     <p><input name="search" type="text" size="40" maxlength="50"/></p>
 <p><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Search" /></p>
</form>
    </div></div>
<?php include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/includes/footer.php");?>
```

Search Results page:

```
<?php require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/includes/session.php");?>
<?php require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/includes/db_connection.php");?>
<?php require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/includes/functions.php");?>

<?php
if (!isset ($_POST['search'])) {
    header("Location:admin.php");
}

$search_sqli="SELECT * FROM profiles WHERE 
    (first_name LIKE '%".$_POST ['search']."%' 
    OR last_name LIKE '%".$_POST ['search']."%' 
    OR first_name2 LIKE '%".$_POST ['search']."%' 
    OR last_name2 LIKE '%".$_POST ['search']."%' 
    OR last_name2 LIKE '%".$_POST ['search']."%' 
    OR city LIKE '%".$_POST ['search']."%' 
    OR agency LIKE '%".$_POST ['search']."%' 
    OR subcomponent LIKE '%".$_POST ['search']."%' 
    OR team_name LIKE '%".$_POST ['search']."%' 
    OR achievement LIKE '%".$_POST ['search']."%' 
    OR profile LIKE '%".$_POST ['search']."%'
        OR year LIKE '%".$_POST ['search']."%')" 
. (isset($_POST['type']) && in_array('1', $_POST['type']) ? " AND medalist='1'" : "")
. (isset($_POST['medal']) && in_array('1', (int)$_POST['medal'] > 0) ? " AND medal='".(int)$_POST['medal']."'" : "");


$search_query=mysqli_query($connection, $search_sqli);
if (mysqli_num_rows($search_query) !=0)  {
$search_rs=mysqli_fetch_assoc($search_query);
}

?>

<?php include("../includes/header-home.php"); ?>
<div class="container">
  <div class="col=md-12">
     <p>Search:</p>
    <form name="form1" method="post" action="search_results.php">
    <input name="search" type="text" size="40" maxlength="50"/>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Search" />

    </form>
   <br />
    <p><strong>Search Results:</strong></p>
  <?php if (mysqli_num_rows($search_query) !=0) {
     do  {
         ?>
    <p><ul>
    <li><a href="view_profile.php?profile=<?php echo urlencode($search_rs["id"]); ?>"><?php echo $search_rs['first_name']; ?> <?php echo $search_rs['last_name']; ?> <?php echo $search_rs['first_name2']; ?> <?php echo $search_rs['last_name2']; ?></a></li></ul></p>     

<?php } while ($search_rs=mysqli_fetch_assoc($search_query));

  } else {
      echo "No results found";
  }
  ?>
  <br />    
  <p> <a class="btn btn-default" href="search.php" role="button">Back to search</a></p>
    </div></div>

<?php include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/includes/footer.php");?>
```

Comment: ***WARNING: SQL Injection Attack Risk ahead!*** I suggest you read this: ["Bobby Tables: A guide to preventing SQL injection"](http://bobby-tables.com/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here: `in_array('1', $_POST['type'])`

the second argument you are passing to `in_array` isn't an array.  It's whatever value you have posted as 'type', and you do something similar in the second instance.  I believe that you could replace the two lines using in_array with:

```
. (isset($_POST['type']) && $_POST['type']=='1' ? " AND medalist='1'" : "")
. (isset($_POST['medal']) && (int)$_POST['medal'] > 0 ? " AND medal='".(int)$_POST['medal']."'" : "");
```

I would also suggest rewriting the first part of your code:

```
<?php require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/includes/session.php");?>
<?php require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/includes/db_connection.php");?>
<?php require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/includes/functions.php");?>

<?php
if (!isset ($_POST['search'])) {
    header("Location:admin.php");
}
```

to avoid the repeated  tags, and also to preprocess those variables, to make your code a little easier to read and maintain.  I would also suggest limiting the type of $_POST['medal'] to `int` to avoid the cast, but it may not be possible in your case.

```
<?php require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/includes/session.php");?>
<?php require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/includes/db_connection.php");?>
<?php require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/includes/functions.php");?>

<?php
if (!isset ($_POST['search'])) {
    header("Location:admin.php");
}

$search_sqli="SELECT * FROM profiles WHERE     
    (first_name LIKE '%".$_POST ['search']."%' 
    OR last_name LIKE '%".$_POST ['search']."%' 
    OR first_name2 LIKE '%".$_POST ['search']."%' 
    OR last_name2 LIKE '%".$_POST ['search']."%' 
    OR last_name2 LIKE '%".$_POST ['search']."%' 
    OR city LIKE '%".$_POST ['search']."%' 
    OR agency LIKE '%".$_POST ['search']."%' 
    OR subcomponent LIKE '%".$_POST ['search']."%' 
    OR team_name LIKE '%".$_POST ['search']."%' 
    OR achievement LIKE '%".$_POST ['search']."%' 
    OR profile LIKE '%".$_POST ['search']."%'
        OR year LIKE '%".$_POST ['search']."%')" 
. (isset($_POST['type']) && in_array('1', $_POST['type']) ? " AND medalist='1'" : "")
. (isset($_POST['medal']) && in_array('1', (int)$_POST['medal'] > 0) ? " AND medal='".(int)$_POST['medal']."'" : "");


$search_query=mysqli_query($connection, $search_sqli);
if (mysqli_num_rows($search_query) !=0)  {
$search_rs=mysqli_fetch_assoc($search_query);
}

?>

<?php include("../includes/header-home.php"); ?>
```

would become:

```
<?php   require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/includes/session.php");
        require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/includes/db_connection.php");
        require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/includes/functions.php");

        if (!isset ($_POST['search'])) { header("Location:admin.php"); }

        $search = $_POST['search'];
        $type    = (isset($_POST['type'])   ? "AND medalist = '1'" : "";
        $medal  = (isset($_POST['medal']) ? "AND medal = '{$_POST['medal']}' : "";


        $search_sqli = "
            SELECT * FROM profiles WHERE (
                    first_name      LIKE '%{$search}%' 
                OR  last_name       LIKE '%{$search}%' 
                OR  first_name2     LIKE '%{$search}%' 
                OR  last_name2      LIKE '%{$search}%' 
                OR  last_name2      LIKE '%{$search}%' 
                OR  city            LIKE '%{$search}%' 
                OR  agency          LIKE '%{$search}%' 
                OR  subcomponent    LIKE '%{$search}%' 
                OR  team_name       LIKE '%{$search}%' 
                OR  achievement     LIKE '%{$search}%' 
                OR  profile         LIKE '%{$search}%'
                OR  year            LIKE '%{$search}%'
            )
            {type}
            {$medal}
        ";

        $search_query = mysqli_query($connection, $search_sqli);
        if (mysqli_num_rows($search_query) !=0)  {
            $search_rs=mysqli_fetch_assoc($search_query);
        }

        include("../includes/header-home.php");

?>
```

I think you'll find that will be easier to read and maintain.  This should work, but I have not tested it live.  If you have any issues I'd be happy to help with them.  Do pay attention to the advice in the comment on your question.  SQL injection is a real danger, and anyone could easily access your database if this is an internet accessible page.  Even if it's internally facing, it wouldn't stop a malicious user from deleting your entire database, or inserting unvalidated data, or viewing any sensitive data you might have in the database.  As your code stands, I would have free access to your data.  mysqli does support several ways of stopping the injection.

Comment: Thank you SO, so much for all of this information. I really appreciate the help. When I change my in-array lines like you suggested, the query works! But when I try to replace all of my beginning code with what you posted, I get syntax errors that I cannot seem to fix :(

Comment: No problem!  Glad I could help.  Sorry I didn't see your comments till now, but I see you figured it out on your own, and that's probably even better.  What was the issue.  If it's in my code, I'll edit it so that it can help someone in the future.

Answer (score 0):

The quick fix is to make the following change :

```
(isset($_POST['medal']) && is_array($_POST['medal']) && in_array('1', $_POST['medal']) === true)
```

As suggested, you should read up on how to process and filter user input data and persist it to the DB.

Comment: Hm, that line is already working, I'm actually trying to fix this line: . (isset($_POST['medal']) && in_array('1', (int)$_POST['medal'] > 0) ? " AND medal='".(int)$_POST['medal']."'" : "");

Comment: So that it calls from my drop down menu "medal"

Comment: Sorry, I've revised my answer to above